# Cinder how to texture an .obj trimesh

Tags: c++, texture-mapping, cinder

I am new to c++/cinder and I am trying to import a 3ds .obj file into cinder and apply a simple texture. I really cant find any simple tutorials on how to do this and it seems to be slightly different to freeGLUT.

```
  gl::Texture sTexture;
  sTexture = gl::Texture(loadImage(loadAsset("texture.jpg")));

  cinder::TriMesh mySphere;
  ObjLoader loader( loadFile( "mySphere/sphere.obj" ) );
  loader.load( &mySphere );
  gl::draw( mySphere );
```

I understand that mySphere constains the texture co-ords as a vector and I need to bind the texture to the object, but I cant find a clear example of how? Everything I have tried has left me with a white circle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution. I was using sTexture.bind(); but sTexture.enableAndBind(); is needed.

```
 gl::Texture sTexture;
 sTexture = gl::Texture(loadImage(loadAsset("texture.jpg")));
 sTexture.enableAndBind();
 cinder::TriMesh mySphere;
 ObjLoader loader( loadFile( "mySphere/sphere.obj" ) );
 loader.load( &mySphere );
 gl::draw( mySphere );
 sTexture.unbind();
```